# .cat.fastq to .cat.fasta file conversion problems

Tags: bioinformatics, data-conversion, fasta, fastq

I'm trying to convert fastq to fasta without doing a quality filter first.  When I try to use fastx toolkit to run this conversion, it gives me an error message when it runs into a low quality base and terminates the conversion so that my converted output ends very early.  (error says something like quality score below -30).

I then tried to use a sed solution posted earlier on this forum about how to convert to fasta using sed.  The line was this:

```
sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p'
```

the line I input to the terminal was:

```
sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' Sample_As_L001_R1.cat.fastq
```

It spit out what I wanted, but printed directly into the terminal.

How do I get this info to not print on the terminal, but to print to an output file?

How do I specify the file/file name that I want the output to go into.  Thanks.

Comment: Just be careful to only use this command on a fastq file that always prints a record as 4 lines.  while 99% of fastq do this, there are some software that use more lines if the sequence is too long.

Answer (score 1):

redirect it to a file

```
sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' Sample_As_L001_R1.cat.fastq > Sample_As_L001_R1.cat.fasta
```